# Create object property names using loop and input textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am refactoring some code where I grab the values inputted into textboxes and use said values for calculations. The problem is rather than using document.getElementByID multiple times I want to loop through each textbox on the page and assigning each value to this object which I will pass to my calculation functions. I would also like to set the property names of this object by looking at the input textbox IDs and using the ID strings for the object property names.

See code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var calcObj = new Object();
    $("input[id^='txt']").each(function(i, val) {
        calcObj[i] = this.value;
    });



    $.each(calcObj, function(i, val) {
        //        alert(val);
    });

});
```

As you can see when document is ready, object is created. There is a jquery .each loop to go through every input with id that contains txt. I am assigning this.value to object where index is i.

So I want to some how name the properties of this object and assign value so I can reference object property name elsewhere in the code where I pass this object to another function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want:

```
calcObj[this.id] = this.value;
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. When I pass my object to my other functions, knowing its property name will help me reference the correct value rather than using document.getElementById. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly get what you're asking for, because it seems like you're already doing what I think you're asking.

Right now, you're doing:

```
calcObj[i] = this.value;
```

That's no different from assigning it like:

```
calcObj['foo'] = this.value;

// and later we can access that via
alert( calcObj.foo );  // or calcObj['foo']
```

You can be dynamic with that as well, like:

```
calcObj[this.id] = this.value;
```